# Problem with inserting data to 'datacharmer/test_db' database

Tags: mysql, database-design

#### The problem

I'm currently trying to insert a new employee to the `employees` table of the test database with the same name.
If I try to add a new employee specifying the `emp_no` it's done with success:

```sql
insert into employees.employees(
    emp_no, 
    birth_date, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    gender, 
    hire_date
) 
values(
    500500, 
    date('1970-05-12'), 
    'John', 
    'Smith', 
    'M', 
    date('1991-10-08')
);
```

But when I try removing the `emp_no`, it won't be incremented by the database.
I'm looking for a way of making the database increment the emp_no itself but Im' not able to find it by myself.

#### The database

[Here](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db)'s the link to the title database itself for the reference.

#### What I tried so far

I tried with a native query as follows:

```sql
insert into employees.employees(
    birth_date, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    gender, 
    hire_date
) 
values(
    date('1970-05-12'), 
    'John', 
    'Smith', 
    'M', 
    date('1991-10-08')
);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```sh
Error Code: 1364. Field 'emp_no' doesn't have a default value
```

So according to the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42941784/12351944), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336520/java-sql-sqlexception-field-supplier-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value/26336586) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918954/java-sql-sqlexception-field-doesnt-have-a-default-value) I tried to enable auto incrementing the `emp_no` with

```sql
ALTER TABLE employees.employees MODIFY emp_no int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

But this gave me another error

```sh
Error Code: 1833. Cannot change column 'emp_no': used in a foreign key constraint 'dept_emp_ibfk_1' of table 'employees.dept_emp'
```

I don't even know if that's what causes the problem and whether I should still go this way or maybe not. Maybe the problem itself lies somewhere else? I'll be very grateful for any help.

Comment: The easiest solution will be to add, in your `INSERT`-statement, a value for `emp_no`.

Comment: I realized that I asked the question the wrong way - the update of it is live now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Github link here is the DDL for the empoyees table with AUTO_INCREMENT property added to the emp_no column:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);
```

The original code posted should work now (without the emp_no).  the double quotes around the dates and strings are still needed.

```
insert into employees.employees(
    birth_date, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    gender, 
    hire_date
) 
values(
    date('1970-05-12'), 
    'John', 
    'Smith', 
    'M', 
    date('1991-10-08')
);
```

Comment: I just realized I asked the question the wrong way (edit incoming) - I'm looking for a way of making the database increment the `emp_no` itself but Im' not able to find it by myself. If you have any idea of the solution, please share :)

Comment: I updated to add the Identity property to the primary key and still fix the quotes :)

Comment: I'll try it and let you know in a few minutes

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 41: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name' at line 2

Comment: the version of mysql is  5.7.31

Comment: I added auto increment to the DDL